# How to resolve some dependencies while building the project through Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I have some Java projects with me and I am trying to build it using Maven in Windows. But I am getting certain errors while doing it. I have used the command as

```
"mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true install"
```

The details is as:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] OpenEMPI Application .............................. SUCCESS [1.610s]
[INFO] OpenEMPI - Core ................................... SUCCESS [1:39.281s]
[INFO] OpenEMPI - OpenPIXPDQ Adapter ..................... FAILURE [48.469s]
[INFO] OpenEMPI - EJB Interface .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] OpenEMPI - Web (Struts 2) ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] OpenEMPI - Web (Server Side) ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] OpenEMPI - Web (Client Side) ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] OpenEMPI - EAR .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:31.203s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jun 08 04:30:04 CDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/60M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project openempi-openpixpdq-adapter: Could not
 resolve dependencies for project org.openhie.openempi:openempi-openpixpdq-adapt
er:jar:2.0.5: Failed to collect dependencies for [javax.ejb:ejb-api:jar:3.0 (pro
vided), org.openhie.openempi:openempi-core:jar:2.0.5 (compile), org.openhealthex
change.openpixpdq:openpixpdq:jar:1.1 (compile), com.misys.braid:braid-base:jar:1
.2.2 (compile), com.misys.hieportal.sysmon:eventmonitoring:jar:1.0 (compile), ca
.uhn.hapi:hapi:jar:0.5.1 (compile), commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.1 (compile
), commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0 (compile), commons-collections:
commons-collections:jar:3.2 (compile), commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3 (compil
e), javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4 (compile), javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0
 (compile), net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.4.1 (compile), org.aspectj:aspectjweave
r:jar:1.6.0 (compile), org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.0 (compile), org.codehaus.x
fire:xfire-java5:jar:1.2.6 (compile), org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-spring:jar:1.2.6
(compile), org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.6.ga (compile), org.hibernate:hiberna
te-annotations:jar:3.3.0.ga (compile), org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotatio
ns:jar:3.3.0.ga (compile), org.jmock:jmock:jar:2.4.0 (compile?), org.jmock:jmock
-junit4:jar:2.4.0 (compile?), org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:2.5.4 (compile
), org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:2.5.4 (compile), org.springframework:sprin
g-aop:jar:2.5.4 (compile), org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:2.5.4 (compile
), org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:2.5.4 (compile), org.jboss.cli
ent:jbossall-client:jar:4.2.3.GA (test), org.jboss:jnp-client:jar:4.2.2.GA (test
), org.subethamail:subethasmtp-wiser:jar:1.2 (test), velocity:velocity:jar:1.4 (
compile), postgresql:postgresql:jar:8.1-407.jdbc3 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.4
 (compile?), log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15 (compile), org.springframework:spring-test:j
ar:2.5.4 (compile?), org.springframework.security:spring-security-core-tiger:jar
:2.0.1 (compile), javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0 (compile)]: Failed to read
 artifact descriptor for org.openhealthexchange.openpixpdq:openpixpdq:jar:1.1: C
ould not transfer artifact org.openhealthexchange.openpixpdq:openpixpdq:pom:1.1
from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo1.mave
n.org refused: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyReso
lutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :openempi-openpixpdq-adapter
```

I want to just ask that how to resolve dependencies if I am getting certain issues.
I don't know much about the maven and hence stuck with such problems

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: **OT**: You should prefer the `-DskipTests` instead of `-Dmaven.test.skip` since the first one will always build your test classes but skip running them while the latter don't even build them. By doing this you know that the build is correct. And there might even be someone using the test artifacts that need them up-to-date. See this [link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html)

Comment: @maba: I tried with your specified option -DskipTests, but the result is same.   :(

Comment: Yes of course. I did not post a solution to your problem, just some other help, hence the OT (off topic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're having this problem because your local machine cannot connect to the main maven repository at this location:  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2.  It's likely you need to configure your maven proxy settings http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, instead of downloading artifacts from Central, try to set up your own "enterprise repository".

- This will lighten the load of this server
- This will lighten the load your enterprise internet bandwidht (mine is very very limited ;)
- You will manage to delpoy you own artifact on.

This only need ... well, a server (physical or virtual) and a tomcat.
You should read this free book : http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/

The main products are :

- Artifactory :http://www.jfrog.com/products.php
- Nexus : http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/
  ...

This is not very difficult, although it appears to be annoying when you thought you just had to install maven, make your pom and go on :)

Answer (score 1):

```
xxx xxx .... from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2):
    Connection to http://repo1.maven.org refused: Connection timed out: connect ->
```

seems when maven tries to download the dependencies from its repositories, it is unable to establish a connection. Few options..

1. make sure your internet connection is available
2. run install without -o switch
3. configure maven proxy settings (
      http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)
4. sometimes some dependencies needed to be download from specific repositories (eg - jboss dependencies from jboss repository ), so might need to add specific repositories to the pom